# Nearby friends on facebook not working

Tags: applications, facebook

I find the nearby friends functions of the facebook app quite useful. However since a few weeks I can't get it to work. Basically I'm stuck with a screen asking me to invite friends.

[image]
[image]

I checked my settings and they look fine. Also inviting friends doesn't solve the issue. Updating/reinstalling the app doesn't fix it.

Comment: I don't use Facebook but is your location disabled?

Comment: No, it's on....

Comment: Yes.. Realised later after seeing map icon. Is it possible that friends around you have declined to be notified? Meaning  that they have not permitted their location to be public?

Comment: I really don't think that's the issue because some time ago I remember being able to see them. Also I don't think it can depend on the location because I remember seeing the position of friends very far away...